# Using TUN/TAP to read incoming data, encapsulate as UDP and transmit

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, udp, tunnel

I have a tun/tap device which is used to read incoming packets from one interface and send them as UDP packets via another interface. I could implement this and could read ICMP pakcets send to the tun/tap interface and also get them remotely using UDP. But the issue happens when I try to change the default gateway of the input interface to the tun/tap device so that I can read all the incoming data from the tun/tap. When this is done, I cant send the UDP packets as the routing isnt proper.

I also tried to you the "SO_BINDTODEVICE" option in socket comm but still didnt work. Please note that I havent used the write() method in the tun/tap. I just used the read() function, collected the data and send them via UDP socket communication.

Please let me know if my approach is wrong or any other work around to overcome this. Thanks.

```
/********More Details********/
```

Thanks Rob.

What I am trying to achieve is a simulation of IP based header commuication(ROHC) in a high latency channel.

For this I have 4 virtual machines. VM1 is a normal desktop machine. VM2 is a gateway which takes the packets using tun/tap(from VM1) and does the UDP based communication with VM4. VM3 is the channel where parameters like latency, error rate etc can be set. VM4 is connected to the WAN. The user in VM1 should be able to browse the WAN just like normal. Please find the diagram below.

```
  IP Packets
  |
  |   +------------------+     +--------------+   +----------------+
  '---|eth1.....         |     |              |   |                |
      |        |         |     |              |   |                |
      |    tun/tap       |     |          eth0|___|UDP Sock    eth0|___
      |        |         |     |              |   |    |       |   |   |
      |        ..UDP Sock|_____|eth1          |   |    |       |   |   |
      |                  |     |              |   |    +tun/tap+   |   '
      +------------------+     +--------------+   +----------------+  WAN
             VM2                 VM3(Channel)             VM4
```

**Update:**

Thanks Tommi. Your solution worked. I could get the UDP packets one way to the final NAT gateway. But I could not get the reverse way to work till now.
I tried enabling the masquerade using iptables and also setting up the host route to the tuntap at VM1 but it wasnot working.
I have a few queries regarding this.
1) In VM4 I receive the UDP data and write to the tun/tap. This will get routed to the WAN by the kernel. But for the incoming packet, do I again need to read using the tun/tap? In this case do I need to make the read and write in different threads? I am asking this because I need to transport them back also as UDP data. Let me know if I am missing something here.
Once again thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've done a good job describing what you have tried. Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish? What is the function of the program you are trying to write? I suspect that the design you have chosen doesn't allow your program to do what you originally intended. Please edit your question and add to the bottom of the question your general goals for your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your udp packets will get routed to your tuntap interface, too. (well, depending on some settings they may just get discarded). You need to add a route rule for the udp peer you are sending them to, a host rule or a smaller network rule that wont interfere with your other communication.

Comment: Thanks Tommi. I will try this way and will let you know.

Comment: Now I see what you are trying to accomplish. Few additional words of advice: remember to put a MASQUERADE rule to VM4 eth0, add a similar host rule to vm4 using the VM1 IP and tun/tap interface, for vm2 it should be sufficient that both its eth1 and eth2 networks are in routing table (with netmasks other than default) and then you can indeed set the default route to the tun/tap device, that way your udp packets to vm3 and the tunneled traffic with vm1 will find their routes. I've done stuff like a lot, feel free to ask if it doesn't seem to work. Also I might have overlooked something.

Comment: Hi Tommi. Please see the update above as I could not write the whole thing in the comment section here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tommi, Just a reminder in case you missed the previous comment. Can you please let me know if it makes sense to implement the read and write functions of tun/tap in different threads? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tommi, Finally I could get the thing to work. As you said the route at the VM4 pointing back to the fist tun tap is right. It wasnt working for me as there was a routing issue between all these interfaces. Now thats fixed and its working fine. For my second query of needing a thread, I have used the select() fuction call to multiplex the read and write request. I have taken this idea from [link]http://www.secdev.org/projects/tuntap_udp/ and from simple tun program of David Brini. Thanks again for ur help :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a few days. Glad things worked out for you. I suggest epoll. A lot like select, but a lot nicer. Threads tend to complicate things needlessly. I mean, when you need threads, you need threads, but when you don't really need them you _really_ don't want them around. :)

Comment: Ok, the way I see the packet flow for return packets. 

1) the vm4 must masquerade the tuntap packets sent out through eth0 to WAN.                            
2) they then come back to vm4, kernel "unmasquerades" them and route them to the tuntap device
3) your epoll fires epollin and you read the packet, then encapsulate it to udp and send it to vm3
   which toys around with it and chucks in onward to vm2.4) vm2 decapsulates the packet and you write out to the tuntap interface
5) vm2 sends it out through eth1 (assuming the original address was from eth1 lan)